# Insert HTML element after a specific div class name with Typescript & Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

What I want to do is to insert a component inside a div, after a specific div with a specific class name. How do I do this in typescript?

```
<div class ="{{order.orderId}}">
    <div class="enter-here"></div>
<other html elements here>
</div>
```

And TypeScript:

```
 insertDiv(){
    insert.component.after.className.enter-here;
 }
```

Comment: you r closing the first div immediately, shouldn't it be closed at last ? eg: `<div class ="{{order.orderId}}">
    <div class="enter-here"></div></div>`

Comment: You're right Dhyey, I changed the question. Thank you.

Comment: can u pls let us know what will be the content of `<div class="enter-here"></div>` ? eg: simple text, list generated with `ngFor` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting new element is not the `angular` way of doing it, when using angular DOM manipulation should be avoided as much as possible. In your question you haven't mentioned what will be the contents of `.enter-here`, so I am assuming it is just plain text:

In your html:

```
<div class ="{{order.orderId}}">
    <div *ngIf="showEnterHereDiv" class="enter-here">
      some text or list which should be visible after showDiv is called
    </div>
    <other html elements here>
</div>
```

In your typescript:

```
// hidden by default
showEnterHereDiv: boolean = false;

...

showDiv() {
    // call this method to show the div
    this.showEnterHereDiv = true;
}

hideDiv() {
    this.showEnterHereDiv = false;
}
```